# Java сравнить и изменить время и дату в файле

Tags: java

Есть java class, в котором в map записаны элементы их время и дата. Приблизительно вот так:

```
new Map <String,String>()
.put("time1","2015-01-25T03:01:00")
```

Нужен метод который будет находить старую дату (before(now)), и менять на новую (буквально на 2,3 дня вперед)

Буду рад любым советам.

Сначала пробовал просто загрузить файл и изменить данные: (в коде очень много лишнего, но работает)

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;

public class FileReplace {
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = null;

    public void  doIt() {
        try {
            File f1 = new File("TFile.java");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(f1);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.contains("2015-01-25T03:01:00"))
                    line = line.replace("2015-01-25T03:01:00", "2016-01-06T08:01:00 ");
                lines.add(line);
            }
            fr.close();
            br.close();

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f1);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            for(String s : lines)
                 out.write(s);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        FileReplace fr = new FileReplace();
        fr.doIt();
    }
    }
```

Потом думаю как то сравнить даты, как то так: (только наброски )

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
               Date date1 = sdf;
             //  Date date2 = ;   data from the file

               if (date1.after(date2)) {

          date2 = data2.replace() // some random future data 

               }
```

Не могу все до кучи свести, и еще нужно достать время и дату с файла, но как писал в начале, она вот так записана.

```
new Map <String,String>()
.put("time1","2015-01-25T03:01:00")
```

Comment: жирновато будет создать класс для такой мелочи)

Comment: Да и классы ваще ниче не делают, а вот метод... это про них:)

Answer (score 1):

> нужно достать время и дату с файла

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Definition_Of_The_File_Creation_Date {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* 
        * Вместо / подстовляем путь к файлу или коталогу, используя статистический
        * метод parsingFolder получаем "карту" заполненую ключём - имя файла (Строка) и 
        * значением даты последнего изменения файла (строка)
        */
        Map<String, String> colection = parsingFolder("/");

        // получаем все ключи нашей колекции
        Set<String> nameFile = colection.keySet();

        // выводим имя файла и его дату 
        for(String name : nameFile){
            System.out.println("Имя: " + name + " DATA: " + colection.get(name));
        }

        /*
        * Можно поменять все ключи методом colection.replace("ключ", "Новое значение"), 
        * Также строку можно разбить java.util.StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(data, "-T:Z")
        * и соответственно записать её через colection.replace("ключ", "Новое значение"), 
        */
        for(String name : nameFile){
            colection.replace(name, "2016-01-06T08:01:00");
            System.out.println("Имя: " + name + " DATA: " + colection.get(name));
        }
    }

    public static TreeMap<String, String> parsingFolder(String nameFolder) {
        // Создаём колекцию, для реализации сохранения данных
        TreeMap<String, String> temp = new TreeMap<String, String>() {};

        // устанавливаем путь к файлу, каталогу
        Path pathFile = Paths.get(nameFolder);
        // определяем является ли путь (nameFolder) каталогом или файлом
        if(Files.isDirectory(pathFile, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
            /* 
            * перебираем каждый файл в каталоге (nameFolder) и записываем 
            * полученные данные в колекцию
            */ 
            try( DirectoryStream<Path> buffer = Files.newDirectoryStream(pathFile) ){
               Iterator<Path> iterratorDirectory = buffer.iterator();

               while(iterratorDirectory.hasNext()) {
                   Path fileDirectory = iterratorDirectory.next();
                   /*
                   * записали имя файла и дату последней модификации файла в колекцию.
                   * Files.getLastModifiedTime - является атрибутом файла, соотвественно вместо можно
                   *    записать и иные данные о файле. Посмотрите методы класса Files типа метод getFileAttrebuteView() 
                   *    readAttributes(), getAttribute() в API java.. там есть все...
                   */  
                   temp.put( fileDirectory.getFileName().toString(), 
                             Files.getLastModifiedTime(fileDirectory, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS).toString() 
                   );
               }
            }catch(SecurityException | IOException exSecuritu){
                System.out.println("ERROR " + exSecuritu);
            }

        } else { 
            /*
            * Данное условие выполняется если указанный при проверки путь являеется файлом
            */
           try{
               // записали имя файла и дату модификации файла в колекцию 
               temp.put( pathFile.getFileName().toString(), 
                         Files.getLastModifiedTime(pathFile, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS).toString() 
               );      
           }catch(IOException ioE) {
                System.out.println("ERROR " + ioE);
           }
        }
        return temp;
    }            
}
```

Далее я просто не пойму, что Вы хотите? зачем менять дату в *.java файле при создании Map.? Если нужно поменять дату у самого файла это один вопрос, дату в коллекции  Map это другой вопрос, если необходимо сохранить коллекцию как файл с данными — то это сериализация и соответственно другой вопрос....... Напишите более подробно пожалуйста, что Вы хотите. Ну либо я уже ответил на Ваш вопрос  :)